# Why do I get different CRC16 result between C# and VB.NET?

Tags: c#, vb.net, crc, crc16

I converted a C# code to VB.NET for CRC16 calculation. However, I got different result on C# and VB.NET. I am confused! Can someone please point me to the right direction?

```cs
    //C# Codes
    UInt16 CalculateCRC(Byte dchar, UInt16 crc16)
        {
            UInt16 mask = (UInt16) (dchar & 0x00FF);
            crc16 = (UInt16)(crc16 ^ mask);

            for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
            {
                UInt16 compare = (UInt16)(crc16 & 0x0001);

                if ( compare == 1)
                {
                    mask = (UInt16)(crc16 / 2);
                    crc16 = (UInt16)(mask ^ 0xA001);
                }
                else 
                {
                    mask = (UInt16)(crc16 / 2);
                    crc16 = mask;
                }
            }

            return crc16;
        }
```

```vb
    'VB.NET Codes
    Private Function CalculateCRC(ByVal dchar As Byte, ByVal crc16 As UInt16) As UInt16
        Dim mask As UInt16 = Convert.ToUInt16((dchar And &HFF))
        crc16 = Convert.ToUInt16((crc16 Xor mask))

        Dim compare As UInt16

        For i As Integer = 0 To 7
            compare = Convert.ToUInt16((crc16 And &H1))

            If compare = 1 Then
                mask = Convert.ToUInt16((crc16 / 2))
                crc16 = Convert.ToUInt16((mask Xor &HA001))
            Else
                mask = Convert.ToUInt16((crc16 / 2))
                crc16 = mask
            End If

        Next

        Return crc16
    End Function
```

```
OUTPUT
```

```
    dchar = 1

    Variable values for each iteration (0 to 7)

    C#
    COMPARE : 0,     1,     0,     1,     0,     1,    0,     1
    MASK    : 32767, 16383, 20479, 10239, 17407, 8703, 16639, 8319,
    CRC16   : 32767, 40958, 20479, 38414, 17407, 33278, 16639, 32894

    VB.NET
    COMPARE : 0,     1,     1,     1,     1,     1,     1,     1
    MASK    : 32767, 16384, 28672, 26624, 25600, 25088, 24832, 24704
    CRC16   : 32767, 57345, 53249, 51201, 50177, 49665, 49409, 49281
```

Can somebody please point me where did I do wrong in the VB codes? Apparantly the C# codes produced the right result.

Comment: Have you compared your code to the results from teleriks converter? http://converter.telerik.com/

Comment: `mask = Convert.ToUInt16((crc16 \ 2))`  (integer division)

Comment: Basic is rounding when dividing by 2.  In basic the mask 32767 / 2 = 16384 which is wrong.

Comment: That worked. Thank you everybody !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Jimi pointed out in a comment, you need to use integer division - also, 'CUShort' should be sufficient:

```vb
Private Function CalculateCRC(ByVal dchar As Byte, ByVal crc16 As UInt16) As UInt16
        Dim mask As UInt16 = CUShort(dchar And &HFF)
        crc16 = CUShort(crc16 Xor mask)

        For i As Integer = 0 To 7
            Dim compare As UInt16 = CUShort(crc16 And &H1)

            If compare = 1 Then
                mask = CUShort(crc16 \ 2)
                crc16 = CUShort(mask Xor &HA001)
            Else
                mask = CUShort(crc16 \ 2)
                crc16 = mask
            End If
        Next i

        Return crc16
End Function
```